# Keeping notifications permanent

Tags: gnome, notification, 21.10

How can I keep GNOME notifications permanant? I need them to say because I can't remember everything, and it would really help if they would stay after I don't click them or when I click them.

Comment: Oh cool thank you :)

Comment: You might consider trying another [flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). The design language in GNOME is "worse is better": the priority is to be clean and consistent above being feature-rich. You can "Try Ubuntu" from a liveUSB to test out different features and settings without affecting your currently installed OS. On GNOME it doesn't appear that you can change the timeout of notifications, nor does it keep a history/log of past notifications.